# create 3 android emulators [phone, tab7, tab10] and start them via commandline for fastlane

Tags: android, android-emulator, continuous-integration, fastlane, screen-grab

I'm working on fastlane and want to start 3 emulators [phone, tab7, tab10] and take screenshots on them.

How do I create a script to create and start emulators via fastlane or commandline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a script which does the following:

1. Start the emulator
2. Wait for the emulator to boot
3. Start screengrab for this emulator
4. Shut down the emulator

Then you call the script for your three different screen sizes.

Some more details:

1. To start the emulator use the program `emulator` which is located under `android-sdk/emulator/emulator`. I had problems with `android-sdk/tools/emulator` so be sure to use the right one. The call can look like this:
   `emulator @'your_emulator_name_variable' &`
   The `&` is important when you are using a shell script to continue after the call.
2. You can call `adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed` to see if the emulator has booted already. Do this in a loop until it returns `1`
3. Call fastlane screengrab and append the specific type flag:
   `--specific-type 'device_type_variable'`
   with `'device_type_variable'` equals to `phone`, `sevenInch` or `tenInch`. According to the emulator you started.
4. Call `adb emulator-5554 emu kill` to shut down you emulator. If it uses another, non standard port, adjust accordingly.

Now you can call this script with the two variables `your_emulator_name_variable` and `device_type_variable` for each of your emulator.

Hope this helps.